# Different Ansible Versions on same macbook

Tags: php, ansible, provisioning

I want to install 2 versions of ansible on my macbook and use it on different vagrant boxes.

What is the best way to seperate 2 different ansible installations.

For example :

My vagrantbox1 require ansible 1.8.4 but my vagrantbox2 needs ansible 2.x.x

I am using pip to install the ansible versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is the standard tool for maintaining "environments" that require different python packages.

Ansible 2.x should be compatible with 1.x, though.

Comment: This seems like only half an answer. Please give an example of how it can be done using virtualenv.

Comment: There are tons of virtualenv howtos.